# knockout js select tv shows

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am a beginner learning knockout js. I am trying to create a section like a day tv program. 

User can select day "Monday" or "Tuesday" by input radio. How does it show the div of the days content.

`<input name="Test" type="radio"  data-bind="checked: tvshows" />Monday 
 <input name="Test" type="radio"   data-bind="checked: tvshows" />Tuesday 
 <div data-bind="hide: ShowMondaytvshows">...</div>

 <div data-bind="hide: ShowTuesdaytvshows">...</div>`

if Monday have select showsMonday 
if user select Tuesday showTuesday tv

Can someone give me a help ?

Comment: Show us your JavaScript? Specifically, your view model and such would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

Your viewmodel

```
function test(){
    var self = this
    self.tvshows = ko.observable('monday')
    self.ShowMondaytvshows = ko.observable(true)
    self.ShowTuesdaytvshows = ko.observable(false)
    self.tvshows.subscribe(function(){
        console.log(self.tvshows())
        if(self.tvshows() == 'monday'){
            self.ShowTuesdaytvshows(false)
            self.ShowMondaytvshows(true)
        }else{
            self.ShowMondaytvshows(false)        
            self.ShowTuesdaytvshows(true)
        }
    })
}

var vm = new test()
ko.applyBindings(vm)
```

And view

```
<input name="Test" type="radio" value="monday" data-bind="checked: tvshows" />Monday 
<input name="Test" value="tuesday" type="radio" data-bind="checked: tvshows" />Tuesday 
<div data-bind="visible: ShowMondaytvshows">Monday programms</div>
<div data-bind="visible: ShowTuesdaytvshows">tuesday programms</div>
```

Notice value in inputs

### Demo